How to create persistent Cookie from HttpContext's Cookie.Append method?
var token = await _jwtTokenService.GenerateToken(user);
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("accessToken", token, new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = false,
    IsEssential = true,
    
});

I am creating an JWT token and attaching it with cookie using HttpContext's Response Method.
I was thinking to use SignInAsync which provides persistent option. But i need jwt for mobile authentication. So I am attching the token in cookie as well as i am returning it.
Now, Every-time i refresh the page, the cookie is deleted and i have to signin. What is the option to persist the cookie which has jwt instead of direct user identity?
I have no idea how to mix JWT with Cookie and make it persistent.

If u have an API makes no sense to send a cookie from the server side. U can create one on the client side and store inside it the JWT token.

No. API and Auth server are same here. So API is responsible here to create the jwt and attach it in cookie. It does that. But the cookie got deleted on refresh. I am very new to asp.net. This is the first time i create a jwt in asp.net. I can make user identity and convert it to cookie and make it persistent. There is support for that in asp.net. This one, i dont know.

I would leave out Expires... that'll make it a session cookie, which is what you'd want here.  You can leave out samesite, secure, and isessential, too.  (as is, those settings are loosening security)  You should be aware of CSRF attacks.  Most API front ends would use tokens sent in custom headers (such as "bearer").  Requiring that header protects against CSRF, but because JS has to read the value can expose the token to XSS.  See here this question to build in to framework:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797587/asp-net-core-store-jwt-in-cookie
